# Drop DB2 constraint using SQL

Tags: sql, db2, constraints

I have a DB2 database called 'test' and I have created a table there using following query.

```
CREATE TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY (
        ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ENTITY_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ENTITY_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        UNIQUE (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME),
        UNIQUE (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_VALUE),
        FOREIGN KEY (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
```

I want to drop the constraint "UNIQUE (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME)" from this table using sql. How can I do that?

### Update

I figured out that I can delete a unique constraint using following command if I have its constraint name.

```
"ALTER TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY DROP UNIQUE <CONSTRAINT NAME>"
```

Also these constraint names are available in the table "sysibm.systabconst" and also in "SYSCAT.TABCONST".

But the problem I still have is, how can I get the name of unique constraint by using the columns associated with it?

Comment: Alter table drop constraint. (You have to find the constraint name first.)

Comment: How can I find that, I checked ' SYSCAT.INDEXES' table, but when I have two databases with same table, I can't retrieve the constraint name for desired table.

Comment: Check `SYSCAT.TABCONST` http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001062.html

Comment: Still I don't see a way to get desired constraint when two databases are available with same tables.

Comment: Since it's a test database, can't you just drop the table and re-create it - this time without that UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: that won't work, I have large number of data where I can't drop and add them again, it seems like 'SYSCAT.INDEXES' table is created per database, in that case I can take constraint name from it.

Comment: Just a tip, always have a script ready to re-create your test database, including insertion of data.

Comment: When you say "two databases", do you really mean "schemas"? Because if they were databases, they would have different `SYSCAT.TABCONST` views...

Comment: How can I get the constraint name of the unique constraint which is associated with columns (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run

```
select INDNAME from SYSCAT.TABCONST WHERE TABNAME='IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY' AND COLNAMES='+ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME
```

Here as result you will get the constraint name: 
eg : SQL160215110206360

Then run

```
ALTER TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY DROP CONSTRAINT SQL160215110206360
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  An index created for a constraint will not necessarily have the same name as the constraint.  As @data_henrik mentions in the comments above, you must look at `SYSCAT.TABCONST` to get proper constraint names.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct the answer, But still I can't get the constraint name using the columns associated for that (Unique) Constraint?

Comment: Corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using `SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE`. Than I am able to drop unique constraint. Otherwise not. The key is in that to find out proper name of constraint. Unique constraint is compound from its own constraint with its name e.g. `SQL190703165844530` and unique index, which has its different own name e.g. `SQL190703165844444`.

```
select * from SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE where TABSCHEMA = <TABSCHEMA> and TABNAME = <TABNAME>;
```

Than it is possible to drop unique constraint and index together by clause
:

```
alter table <TABLE_NAME> drop unique <CONSTRAINT_NAME>;
```